# Remove first word conditionally

Tags: unix, sed

How can I remove first word from each line in a file, if it contains multiple words?

File:

```
test test2
test3
test4 test5 test6
test7
```

Result:

```
test2
test3
test5 test6 
test7
```

Also, how can I save only last word from above file, i.e.,

result2:

```
test2
test3
test6
test7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sed solution: if the line contains a space, we know that there are several words, so we delete everything up to and including the first space.

```
$ sed '/ /s/[^ ]* //' infile
test2
test3
test5 test6
test7
```

For the opposite, we check again for a space; if there is one, we remove everything up to and including the last space (`.*` is greedy).

```
$ sed '/ /s/.* //' infile
test2
test3
test6
test7
```

If the words aren't separated by spaces, but for example tabs, we can replace all instances of a space above with `[[:blank:]]`:

```
sed '/[[:blank:]]/s/[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]//' infile
```

et cetera.

Checking for the space/blank is not strictly necessary: if there isn't one, the substitution doesn't do anything, so

```
sed 's/[^ ]* //' infile
```

and

```
sed 's/.* //' infile
```

would also work, but checking for the blank expresses the intent more clearly, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the 1st word of each line,

```
cut -d' ' -f2- fileName
```

To get the last word of each line and save it in a new file,

```
awk '{print $NF}' fileName > newFileName
```